# apache-poi error when attempting to get cell string from evaluated formula: NotImplementedFunctionException: CONVERT

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm attempting to evaluate formula cells in an xlsx workbook with apache-poi like so:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("files/records/RFQ.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
Sheet structureBomSheet = workbook.getSheet("Structure BOM");

DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
FormulaEvaluator objFormulaEvaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(workbook);

Row row = structureBomSheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);

logger.info(df.formatCellValue(valueCell));
objFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(valueCell);
String cellValue = df.formatCellValue(valueCell, objFormulaEvaluator);
logger.info(cellValue);
```

In the above code, df.formatCellValue gives prints out the formula in the cell, and using formateCellValue() with an objForumlaEvaluator gives me the following error:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: CONVERT
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.atp.AnalysisToolPak$NotImplemented.evaluate(AnalysisToolPak.java:59)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.UserDefinedFunction.evaluate(UserDefinedFunction.java:61)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:129)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:514)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:278)
... 150 more
```

How can I get the string derived from my formula out of the cell?

Comment: What is in the cell?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? If not the latest, what happens if you upgrade?